# Incase sensitive search in data that are upper-lower case

Tags: elasticsearch

I have these data:

```
first_name: "Juraj"
last_name: "Carnogursky"
```

When I do search `juraj` I want to find that record. So basically I want the data to be transformed to lowercase and then compared to the expression. What I've got so far is not working:

```
"query":{
        "bool":{  
            "should":[  
                {  
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "title.keyword:*" + expression + "*"
                    }
                },
                {  
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "description.keyword:*" + expression + "*"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "author.first_name.keyword:*" + expression + "*"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "author.last_name.keyword:*" + expression + "*"
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    },
```

What I had before was this:

```
    "query":{
        "bool":{  
            "should":[  
                {  
                    "wildcard":{  
                        "title.keyword":"*" + expression + "*"
                    }
                },
                {  
                    "wildcard":{  
                        "description.keyword":"*" + expression + "*"
                    }
                },
                {  
                    "wildcard":{  
                        "author.first_name.keyword":"*" + expression + "*"
                    }
                },
                {  
                    "wildcard":{  
                        "author.last_name.keyword":"*" + expression + "*"
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    },
```

These two aren't working when I type my name lowercase.
How to fix this?

**EDIT**

Here is my mapping http://pastebin.com/nnFZHf08

PS: sorry for the external link the mapping is too long...

Comment: please show your mappings

Comment: Remove `.keyword` (i.e. search on the `text` field, not the `keyword` one which is not analyzed) and it will work.